# How to get the URL from which a link was clicked?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I currently have a generic link to download files in several blade files, and in each page it downloads a different file (based on the page it's on):

I want to be able to log from which page (if any), it was downloaded from.

so if for example the download link was in example.com/some/file

I want to get `example.com/some/file` (or `/some/file`) instead of `example.com/download_route`

I know that this link can be called from an API Platform like Postman, but still I would like to get some information (And is it possible to somehow actually secure it so that it's less likely to get wrong information? Or it can always be tempered with?)

Comment: $referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; Contains the URL of the previous page.

Comment: I read that I should not be using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` as it's not reliable?

Answer (score 0):

```php
url()->previous()
```

From documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/urls#accessing-the-current-url